# Read a textfile.txt of random numbers from the command line argument and find the sum

Tags: c

hope some experts can help me. It's my first time posting on Stack so please be patient with me. Thanks.
Here are a list of my problems:

1. Tried to open a text file from argv[1] but the program showed NULL
2. Tried to use fgetc to read in one character at a time. When hit "white_space", put ('2.2') in a buff, add a '\0', then use sscanf to turn it into a double type. Not sure if this approach is right.

Here is my code:

```
/*
 * This program computes simple statistics from a file of ASCII numbers
 */

/* 
 * File:   statsMain.c
 * Author: William Vu T Nguyen
 * ID: C0436847
 * Created on February 6, 2017, 12:10 PM
 */

#include "statistics.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void printStats(FILE *dest, const int count, const double mean,
        const double ssdev);

// main program

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE *pFile;
    int count;
    int x;
    char buff[100] = {0};
    char *pBuff = buff;
    double numVal;
    double sum;
    double sumsq;
    double calculatedMean;
    double calculatedStdDev;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s dataFileName\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        if ((pFile = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open input file \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            while ((x = fgetc(pFile)) != EOF) {
                *pBuff = x;
                sscanf(pBuff, "%lf", &numVal);
                sum += numVal;
                sumsq += (sum * sum);
                count++;
                pBuff++;                
            }           

            calculatedMean = mean(sum, count);
            calculatedStdDev = ssdev(sum, sumsq, count);
            printStats(pFile, count, calculatedMean, calculatedStdDev);
        }
        fclose(pFile);
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void printStats(FILE *dest, const int count, const double mean,
        const double ssdev) {
    char str[100] = {0};

    sprintf(str, "%d Values, Mean = %lf, Sample Standard Deviation = %lf"
            , count, mean, ssdev); //deal with buffer
    puts(str);
    fprintf(dest, "%s", str);
}
```

If my code shows that I'm a novice in C then please be patient as I'm still in my learning stage. I love programming, circuit design, and microcontroller. Did horribly in school when learning those subjects but I never let it be a determined factor of my life. Thanks.

Comment: 1) There should be two questions instead of one: the first one is "why `fopen()` returns `NULL`?", the second is "do I correcly deal with the file's data?". The first one would have an obvious answer: `fopen()` is defined to return `NULL` on error, and then you're supposed to check the `errno` value, which you didn't. You might want to learn about `perror()` and `strerror()`. If on a POSIX system, read then `errno(3)` manual page. Answering the second one would require knowledge of the file's format, so you should include an excerpt from it in your question.

Comment: All in all, questions of the form "is doing XXX is a correct approach at solving YYY?" are unfit for the StackOverflow format -- try https://programmers.stackexchange.com for informal discussions / code reviews.

Comment: I would hence vote to close the question in its current form as I think it's impossible to edit it to match the SO's guidelines. Please consider asking two separate questions instead -- as I suggested.

Comment: @kostix Programmers (now known as Software Engineering) is for high level, generally non-code questions. That said, the OP said they are having specific issues with the code,but hinted some version of the code may work. If the question can be rephrased to focus on the "working" part, it may be on-topic for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) granted the on-topic guidelines are followed.

Comment: What does the text file look like? It would help to see if you are reading it right.

Comment: Point taken. Thanks. Next time I will post separate questions to ensure no overlapping between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You're also:

- passing `pFile` which was opened as read only, and trying to write to it
- using `sum`, `sumsq`, and `count` without initializing them
- probably making a mistake with `sumsq += (sum * sum);`

It's better to take advantage of inherent `stdin` and `stdout` file pointers, then you can do stuff like:

```
stats < input_file > output_file
```

Where `stats` is your program. If you're using Linux, you can chain your program to `tee` and do exactly what you're trying to do (i.e. output to console and file) but with no extra code.

How I would write it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "statistics.h"

void printStats(const int count, const double mean, const double ssdev);

int main() {
    int count = 0;
    double numVal, sum = 0.0, sumsq = 0.0;
    double calculatedMean, calculatedStdDev;

    while (scanf("%lf", &numVal)) {
        sum += numVal;
        sumsq += numVal * numVal;
        count++;
    }

    calculatedMean = mean(sum, count);
    calculatedStdDev = ssdev(sum, sumsq, count);
    printStats(count, calculatedMean, calculatedStdDev);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void printStats(const int count, const double mean, const double ssdev) {
    printf("%d Values, Mean = %lf, Sample Standard Deviation = %lf\n",
        count, mean, ssdev);
}
```

Comment: Point taken. Thanks for your input. I tried to open the read only file using command line argument as part of my lab. I did rewrite the code but now I run into another problem. However, that is for another time. Thanks.